# Applescript - set Messages inputTextArea error

Tags: applescript

I am trying to set text of the Messages app. I used some helper tool to generate applescript code. Enabled in privacy/accessibility. Still getting compilation errors ("A number can’t go after this identifier."). 10.12.6

```
tell application "Messages"     
    set value of textarea 1 of scroll area 4 of splitter group 1 of window "Messages"  to "Hello World!" 
end tell
```

Any advice how to get/set value?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra

```
activate application "Messages"
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    set value of text area 1 of scroll area 4 of splitter group 1 of window "Messages" of application process "Messages" to "Hello World"
end tell
```

Comment: Change window  "messages" to window 1 and it works. Many thanks!

Comment: @MarekH   There is a problem with your suggestion “Change window "messages" to window 1 and it works”… If the messages window is the only window open, your solution will work.  However, if you have other windows open in your messages app (file transfer window, buddy list window, etc.), and either of those windows is the front most... The script throws an error because now the messages window is no longer “window 1”.  My version of the script will not throw an error.  It will input the text correctly

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.